# How to color sympy graphs in a specific way

Tags: python, plot, sympy

I am trying to make a 3d graph of the function 1/x with 2d inputs for x.
The coloring shown is based on the z axis. However, I would rather have the coloring be based on the equation given to it. x=|x|*e**(theta * i)
[image]

I want the coloring to be based more on theta (the angle from the z=0 line of the input, x.) like the picture below.
[image]

```
def graph(fx='1/x',jump_scaler=0.1,min_x=1, max_x=10,jump=inf):
    if jump>jump_scaler*abs((min_x-max_x)/10.0):
        jump=abs((min_x-max_x)/10.0)*jump_scaler

    np.seterr(divide='ignore',invalid='ignore')
    principle_x=Symbol('principle_x')
    theta=Symbol('theta')
    eti=e**(theta*1j)
    x=eti*principle_x
    y=eval(fx)

    p=plot3d_parametric_surface(principle_x,re(y),im(y),(principle_x,min_x,max_x),(theta,0,2*pi),adaptive=True, nb_of_points=(max_x-min_x)/jump*2*pi/jump,title=fx,xlabel='x',ylabel='re(y)',zlabel='im(y)',show=False)
    p[0].surface_color = lambda theta=theta: theta
    print(p[0])
    p.show()
graph()
```

[image]

I obviously don't know how this works. How do I do this?

Also, how do I add a label for the z axis? I don't really care if you don't answer this, though.